# Trying to run a batch file from local machine (not a server) to execute on every machine in the domain

Tags: batch-file, cmd

First time posting here, so I apologize for any miscues ahead of time.

I am trying to create a batch file that can be run from my local machine to every machine in the domain. We have a program that periodically decides not to run on users' pcs, and our temporary workaround is for us to manually run a line of code from our local to start it. The code is as follows:

```
sc \\(user's computer name) start mtappmanager
```

for simplicity's sake, I have created the following batch file, which has made running the code much quicker:

```
@ECHO OFF
echo.
SET /P cname=Enter computer number:
sc \\%cname% start mtappmanager
echo.
echo.
echo *** Ask the user to try now.
echo.
echo.
pause
```

Unfortunately, the user does still have to call us in order for us to run it, so I'd like it to run automatically, without user (or our) intervention.

Our computers follow a simple numbering format of C(4-digit number) or L(4-digit number) so they would appear as C1214 or L0657, for example. It is important that the computer "number" has exactly 4 digits, requiring an appropriate number of 0s to preceed, if necessary. Running the code for a computer that is already running the program does no damage, so I'd like a way to run it on every computer that's connected, and possibly set it to run on a timed loop. (300 sec, for ex) I originally tried a sequential numbering sequence, but I couldn't figure out how to input it at that point in the code, or how to ensure the 4 digit numbering sequence.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of computers in the domain, you could simply use a loop.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%c IN ('TYPE "C:\Users\me\computerlist.txt"') DO (
    SC \\%%~c START mtappmanager
)
```

If you are going to run this every 300 seconds, I doubt if you want to ask the user to try again every time.

To go further with this, it would be helpful to use PowerShell. This would allow you to query for a list of computers in the AD domain, test if they are available, test if the service is already running, start a service if needed, and send an email to a user.

Comment: There is no .txt file to reference, but your solution involving PowerShell actually sounds like a better one than I suggested. Could you provide a sample on how I could get that done? Also, is there something similar to a batch file within PS that could execute this with a single operation?

Comment: This is not a totally trivial thing to write. SO is not a free script writing service. I would suggest that you investigate `Get-ADComputer`. There are 25,000+ computers on my network, but you can filter it. You will still need something to connect the computer to a user's email.

Comment: What if you gave the user a script to run that would start the service and, if not, send an email containing the information needed for your script (.bat or .ps1) to restart it remotely?

Comment: Thank you lit. I wasn't suggesting you write the entire code, only a sample of what could be done. I apologize if that's how it came off. I am very new to scripting, which is why I am here asking questions. As for providing a script to the user, it won't work because users' access is restricted from starting services. (That was my first attempt at a solution, actually) In any case, thank you for your help. I will see what I can come up with.

Comment: Scripting is a big world. What if the user ran something that sent a message to something that could start the service as an administrative account?